# Missing BJT parameter, \$I_b\$ max

Tags: transistors, current, bjt

After 40+ years you would think I would know this, somehow it never came up, but for the life of me I don't see it.

[Typical transistors specs](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/38359.pdf) list a plethora of values but one that always seems to be missing is \$I_{b_{MAX}}\$. That is, the maximum current you can pass through the base emitter junction.

Obviously you can't exceed the power rating across the base-emitter diode forward drop, so 626mW/0.7V ~ 900mA, but I have a feeling there is a fusing number for the bonding wire. Perhaps it is the same as the max collector current.. 200mA.

What number is the right one, if any?

Comment: I have seen it listed but I’m racking me brain to think on what. It was to do with a question on this site so maybe bc547, 2n3904 or maybe 2n2222.....

Comment: It would be related to secondary breakdown due to current crowding, but that's normally spec in the SOA plot for IC-VC. It would be less than IC max

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/158522/bjt-absolute-maximum-base-current

Comment: Found one on an ST BD139 datasheet: 0.5A.

Comment: Generally it is shown in power transistors' (BD139, BD243, 2N3055 etc) datasheets. But I cannot say the same thing for general purpose ones.

Comment: You would think it would be a critical one that was always listed huh... odd.

Comment: Often rather large .

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the answers [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/158522/bjt-absolute-maximum-base-current/158528#158528) the [NXP BC847](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BC847_SER.pdf) lists a maximum Ibm as 100mA for a <= 1ms pulse.

[image]

It is less than the maximum collector current under the same conditions.

Comment: Yup seen those, but no indication of continuous. I was toying with an idea to use the BE as a diode in a current detection circuit for a [different question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/353458/distributing-an-electrical-current) , but the current gets a tad large.

Comment: Maybe 50% if Ic is a good ball-park number in general though.

Comment: @Trevor_G Depends on how brave you are. 10mA is mentioned in the testing of Vbe.

Answer (score 1):

The assembly house will use the same size bond wire for all 3 leads. Unless the base metallization from bond-pad into the base region has narrow metal, I'd use the same # as emitter or collector. Some old datasheets would, with pride, show die photos.